# How does the Cloud SQL socket know what domain to connect to?

Tags: sockets, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I don't have a lot of experience with sockets, especially google cloud ones. The Cloud SQL uses a format: `mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME;dbname=DATABASE`

How does this get translated into making a real connection? To me it seems like it is missing a domain name.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/cloud-sql/using-cloud-sql-mysql

```
env_variables:
  # Replace USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE, and CONNECTION_NAME with the
  # values obtained when configuring your Cloud SQL instance.
  MYSQL_DSN: mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME;dbname=DATABASE
  MYSQL_USER: USER
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 1):

Sockets on Linux are just `folders` that are `CHMOD 777`

In this case you need to create a directory `/cloudsql` and CHMOD 777.

Better documentation found for this by visiting https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/using-cloud-sql and clicking `UNIX Sockets` as the doc option.

Also you need to download the `cloud sql proxy` app, these are all just settings for it.